# Export.map.toCloudStorage() doesn't work on private buckets

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-cloud

I'm trying to export an image on a google cloud bucket in earth engine:

```
var uri = "gs://private_bucket-1/path_to_my_COG.tif"
var cloudImage = ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF(uri);
cloudImage = cloudImage.updateMask(cloudImage.eq(0)).toInt();

print(cloudImage);


var vizParams = {
  palette: ['red']
};


Map.addLayer(cloudImage, vizParams);
Map.centerObject(cloudImage, 15);
// the image exists and is properly formatted

Export.map.toCloudStorage({
  image: cloudImage,
  description: 'mapTilesFromEE',
  bucket: "gee_objects_public",
  fileFormat: 'auto',
  maxZoom: 13,
  writePublicTiles: false
});
```

Everything works fine until I'm saving in a public bucket, however if I set the export on a private bucket it runs 5 times and then sends a generic error:

Error: Internal error. (Error code: 13)

which doesn't mean nothing basically

Any suggestion? The documentation is not very verbose on the topic